# Can't install anything because of "spacenavd"

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation

I tried to install something called spacenav a while ago to try using a fancy mouse with my computer, but it didn't work. Here s what happened just now when I tried to install ntfs-config

```
$ sudo apt install ntfs-config
```

and I got

```
Need to get 0 B/74.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 776 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.6) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S99spacenavd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'spacenavd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and procps if started
insserv:  loop involving service procps at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service spacenavd and hwclock if started
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop at service spacenavd if started
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 2
insserv: There is a loop between service spacenavd and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting spacenavd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: There is a loop between service spacenavd and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't care about fixing the mouse issue

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could try "uninstall" spacenavd.
Currently aptitude is still trying to complete that installation.
Running the follow should remove it from the list of apps to try to install:

```
sudo apt-get remove spacenavd
```

once that completes I imagine your command (
    `sudo apt install ntfs-config` ) will complete.

Comment: I get the same error above when I try to remove it

Answer (score 0):

I followed the comments in this thread and fixed the problem. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/284708

The command was

```
$ sudo rm -v /etc/rc*/*spacenavd
```

and the output was

```
removed '/etc/rc2.d/S99spacenavd'
```

Note that the problem in the linked thread is something called `runmbbservice`, and my problem was `spacenavd`. The linked thread says that the file was empty, but mine wasn't.

The output of

```
$ cat -n /etc/init.d/spacenavd
```

on my computer was

```
 1  #!/bin/sh
 2  #
 3  # spacenavd      free driver for 3Dconnexion 6dof devices
 4  #
 5  # chkconfig: 2345 99 99
 6  # description: A free user space driver for 3Dconnexion input devices,\
 7  #              compatible with the proprietary 3dxsrv daemon.
 8  
 9  DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/spacenavd
10  
11  [ -x "$DAEMON" ] || exit 0
12  
13  case "$1" in
14  start)
15      echo 'Starting spacenavd daemon'
16      $DAEMON -v
17      ;;
18  
19  stop)
20      echo 'Stopping spacenavd daemon'
21      # detect daemon's process id
22      pid=`cat /var/run/spnavd.pid 2>/dev/null`
23      if [ $? != 0 ]; then
24          pid=`ps -e | grep spacenavd | awk '{ print $1 }'`
25          if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
26              echo 'spacenavd daemon is not running, nothing to do.'
27              exit 1
28          fi
29      fi
30      kill $pid
31      ;;
32  
33  reload|restart|force-reload)
34      $0 stop && sleep 1 && $0 start
35      ;;
36  esac
```

I used the command `$ locate spacenavd` to find the files I needed to remove, as per the instructions in the linked thread.